# How can i get this value with XPATH in JMeter

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I have a webservice response as such :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Body>
     <FileResponse xmlns="http://xxx.x.sx.be">
        <id>090150e080249d09</id>
     </FileResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am trying to extract the value of "id" but i can't seem to figure out the right query. I used an online generator which provided :

```
/soap:Envelope[@xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"]/soap:Body/FileResponse[@xmlns="http://xxx.x.sx.be"]/id/text()
```

But it doesn't seem to work in Jmeter as the response is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this to be the answer : `//*[local-name() = 'id']`

Answer (score 0):

Your test for the namespace is invalid.  Xpath queries do not support this.

Instead you will need to JMeter to pass in the namespaces declarations along with the xpath query.  I dont know how JMeter does that but I can give you an xpath expression that may work around it.

```
//*[local-name()='FileResponse']/*[local-name()="id"]/text()
```

The xpath will test the name of the node and ignoring the namespaces.  Its not recomended practice to test without namespaces and could be slow but it'll work.